# PDFJsAnnotations Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, json, pdf, pdf.js, pdf-annotations

tried to load saved json from local storage using `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CanvaData"))`

```
  ready() {
    console.log("Plugin initialized successfully");

    var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CanvaData"));
    console.log(arr)
    // localStorage.clear();
    pdf.loadFromJSON(arr)
  },
```

but as you can see it's throwing `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` .

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after investigating for hours i found the issue that causes this.

i saved the json into local storage as a single string

```
localStorage.setItem('CanvaData', JSON.stringify(pdf.serializePdf()));
```

now i changed it to save the data as json to local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('CanvaData', pdf.serializePdf());
```

after that i modified the load from json as the following:

```
ready() {
    console.log("Plugin initialized successfully");

     var data123 = localStorage.getItem('CanvaData');
     pdf.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(data123))
  },
```

Fixed.